# Writing a gem supporting compiled languages with Rake. How to test?

Tags: tdd, ruby, rake

I want to create a gem that extends the functionality of Rake, creating commands for compiling .NET code.*

Basically, I want to be able to write a Rakefile like this:

```
desc "Build main executable"
fsc :build do |t|
  t.output_file = "nde.exe"
  t.output_folder = "output"
  t.source_files << "main.fs"
  t.packages << "packages/Nancy"
end

task :default => [:clean, :build]
```

So just like the `file` function in rake creates a FileTask, the `fsc` function should create a compilation task.

I created a POC where I have the code inlined in the Rakefile - and it gives me an idea on how to do it. The next step is to isolate it into a gem.

The central point in my POC is the following function:

```
def create_compilation_task
  task_dependencies = source_files | assembly_refs 
  dest = File.join output_folder, output_file
  Rake::FileTask::define_task dest => task_dependencies do |t|
    refs = assembly_refs.map { |r| "-r:#{r}" }.join(" ")
    output = "--out:#{dest}"
    target = "--target:exe"
    sources = source_files.join(" ")
    system "fsharpc #{output} #{refs} #{target} #{sources}"
  end
end
```

But how do I write tests for such a gem?

I created this skeleton test code:

```
describe 'F# compiler' do
  it 'compiles code' do
    @app = Rake::Application.new
    Rake.application = @app
    Rake::Task::define_task :build do
    end
    @app[:build].invoke()
  end
end
```

This does indeed call the task defined in the context of the test. Are there any problems writing the test code in this manner?

**Independence from file system**

The problem domain is that of files on the disk, and internally I have used `FileTask` objects to represent both input and output files, as I can take advantage of Rake's build optimization feature.

But how do I test this, e.g. verifying that the output is indeed not generated when it is newer than all inputs. I could verify the chain of `Task` instances being created, but that would be testing an implementation detail. I would much rather execute the task and verify the behavior.

Is there a way to start the Rake infrastructure up with a mocked file system, or do I create a temporary folder on disk during a test run?

**Verifying system commands being called**

I use the `system` function to call an external program. I would very much like to avoid calling the F# compiler during testing, so instead I need to capture the call `system` call.

Verifying the call should also not be too specific, i.e. it shouldn't determine if the command is equal to some expected string. When I verify that the compiler has been called with the correct source files, that test must not fail if compiler optimization options have been modified.

I imagine that using a standard CLI argument parser gem could be used.

* I am aware of the Albacore gem, but that compiles msbuild projects, where I want to compile source code files directly.